# Maven command/plugin to change package structure of generater jar

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

Package Structure of my generated jar is `com/ipc/session/...`

I need the jar to be in `car/com/ipc/session/...` format.

Is there any maven command or plugin to achieve this?

Comment: Why doing it via Maven? Change your packages in `src/main/java` from `com/ipc/session/...` to `car/com/ipc/session/...` and you`re done. Furthermore, I don't think that your class files will like it if you change their package structure without letting them know, i.e. after compiling them.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. We need 2 jars as part of Maven build. 1. Normal jar with proper package structure, 2. Jar with different package structure(specified in my question). Apologies for missing this in my question.

Comment: What's the purpose of 2.? Why and when do you need this compared  to 1.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shade plugin it is possible. It worked for us. Thanks all for providing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My 0.02$
Just becoz i am not sure about your usecase, having 2 jars means, you are creating 2 kinds of dep jars that will be used by 2 systems/softwares. Ideally its bad to have different packaging and its probably going against our design mechanism and reusability being lost.

Also, according to Maven (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html), what you are asking for is not supported.

Hope this helps.

-Praveen